# segmented control in navigation bar broke with latest Xcode 9.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, constraints, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an app with a segmented control in the navigation bar as a navigation item that when I build with Xcode 9.2 is broken.  Doesn't respond to touches in two of the segments and it is not positioned correctly anymore (should appear centered in the nav bar)  Nothing has changed in the project.  I.e. I build the same version that is approved in the app store.

Any ideas what may have changed with Xcode that could be causing this?  I'm targeting 9.1 so it isn't anything to do with iOS 11. When I go into story board the segmented control isn't appearing inside the View anymore it is off by itself in a blank part of the story board (see second image below).

Update: If I remove all constraints for the segmented control then it appears in the correct location but I still can't see or select it in storyboard.

[image: Moved and broken segmented control]

[image]

Comment: Try adding flexible space at left most index and then segment control.